# Error in Rbindlist from a rasterstack and shapefile extraction file

Tags: python, shapefile, r, rasterstack, databinding

I have multiple rasters files and a grid shapefile.

I load  the shapefile:

```
grid = st_read('/grid.shp')
```

I load the raster and create a raster stack

```
`path <- "/VI_tif"`  #folder where I have stored the raster data
    dlist <- dir(path,pattern="VCI.tif")


    for (i in 1:length(dlist)) {                   
      fold <- paste(path,dlist[i],sep="/")         
      fls <- dir(fold,pattern="VCI.tif")              
      flsp <-paste(fold,fls,sep="/")               
      vcistack <- stack(flsp)
```

Then, I extract the variable from the vcistack according to my grid shapefile:

```
vci.grid <- exact_extract(vcistack, grid, include_cols=T, include_xy=T, force_df=T)
```

Finally, I want to transform the list into dataframe:

```
vci.grid.df <- rbindlist(vci.grid, fill=T, use.names = T)
```

However, I got the following error message:

> Error in  rbindlist(vci.grid, fill = T, use.names = T) :
> Column 1 of item 1 is length 225 inconsistent with column 9 which is length 50625. Only length-1 columns are recycled

Which I don't understand because when I look at it there are 225 rows, not 50625.

Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: Hard to tell without either your data or some information about it - plots, summaries, etc.

Comment: The data is very huge and it's a list. I did not know what kind of sample I could show you.